# How do I deal with taxes on a U.S. Savings Bond that matured a few years before it was redeemed?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, interest, savings-bonds

My parents recently found a 30-year Savings Bond of mine that matured in 2016. I redeemed it at the bank in late 2019. My understanding is the correct way to handle this is to file an amended 2016 return (before April 15, 2020). I don't want to do this because the bank sent me a 2019 1099-INT for the redemption, so I suspect the IRS will see that I don't report it on my 2019 taxes and either send me a notice or automatically adjust my return, in which case I end up paying tax on the interest twice. It's hard for me to believe the IRS is advanced enough to see a 2019 1099-INT but realize it's for a Treasury bond that matured in an earlier year. So can I just report it on my 2019 return and pay the tax this year? I have to imagine this is a common occurrence, and most people have no idea about the rules, and would do exactly that.

Comment: Since you didn't redeem the bond until 2019, I think your assumption that you need to amend the 2016 return is incorrect. The taxable event is the redemption, not the maturation.

Comment: @chepner That would certainly make things easier, but according to https://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/indepth/ebonds/res_e_bonds_eetaxconsider.htm#when, you owe interest when the earlier of either (1) you redeem the bond or (2) it reaches final maturity. Everything I find online seems to confirm this.

Comment: Ah, OK. I'm not sure if I should leave my comment (and your response) as a clarification of the question, or just delete the evidence of my ignorance :)

Comment: @chepner I envy your ignorance. I suspect I could just put it on my 2019 tax return and never think about it again, but I had to go and research it... :-)

Comment: Note this is a _Savings_ Bond, which is not what the words 'Treasury bond' normally mean in a finance context. Savings Bonds have special tax status; for a standard (marketable) bond you must report and pay tax on the interest and any OID (amortized discount) every year, for a Savings Bond you can defer until maturity redemption or sale -- but as noted, not _after_ that. (In some cases, but not this one, you can exclude the income entirely if the bond is used for higher education expenses.)

Comment: (fixed) Craig: although they didn't list your case as one of the motivations, it looks to me like you can amend 2016 as required and for 2019 use [this procedure in pub 550 for 'US savings bond interest previously reported'](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p550#en_US_2018_publink100010051). To be on the safe side, if you normally e-file, you might wait until the amendment is processed (which will take longer because it's paper) before filing the new return, even if that means using a 4868 extension.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I had just assumed Treasury bonds and Savings bonds were the same thing. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 This seems like a lot of work for a lost Savings Bond--I think the amendment to my 2016 taxes will in turn affect my 2017 and 2018 taxes. What are the consequences if I simply include it in my 2019 tax return?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if it affects other years -- (nonbusiness) interest doesn't interact with any carryover items I know of. That said, while doing it in '19 rather than '16 is technically wrong, as long as you report and pay in _some_ year I doubt they'll pursue it; the difference is probably only interest of about 6%, and they have plenty of people who don't report or pay _at all_ who are higher priority than you. Plus as you said probably other people in this situation don't even know about the rule.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I have an ongoing passive activity loss limitation. So changing my AGI in 2016 would have a domino effect on subsequent years.

Comment: Ah - I feel your pain. I once needed to amend 3 consecutive years for a similar reason, and as it was near the refund statute limit I mailed them all together. Mistake. They were processed out of sequence and rejected, and it took two years for Appeals to resolve. I agree with taking the _tiny_ risk, and wish you luck.